# Console.WriteLine not printing the second argument

Tags: c#

I am trying to add two integers using a method in the `switch case`. I want to show the answer by calling `WriteLine`, but the result does not show.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Simple Calculator\n\t" +
        " 1) Add\n\t" +
        " 2) Subtract\n\t" +
        " 3) Multiply\n\t" +
        " 4) Divide\n\t" +
        " 5) Quit\n\t", input);

    Console.Write("Enter Selection: ");
    input = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine());

    switch (input)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Results:", Add(num1,num2));
            break;
    }          
}

public static double Add(double num1, double num2)
{
  return num1 + num2;
}
```

Comment: write it as Console.WriteLine("Result: "+ Add(num1, num2))

Comment: You really should be more specific than "the result does not show" - give expected and actual output. Also, I changed your title to focus on the actual problem. In future, please construct a [**Minimal**, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - if you had done so, you'd likely have ended up with a 1-line program similar to `Console.WriteLine("Results:", 1);`, which, with proper research effort, would've resulted in you looking up an example on how to use `WriteLine`, and not having asked a question at all, or being able to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies in how you are using `Console.WriteLine` and string formatting.

```
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", Add(num1, num2))
```

Is what you want.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**EDIT** @narakaya mentioned you can also take advantage of implicit string casting and just `+` the two arguments:

```
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + Add(num1, num2))
```

Answer (score 0):

When You write `Console.WriteLine("Results:",Add(num1,num2));` you don't send the argument to  the `WriteLine` Method. you should try: `Console.WriteLine("Results {0}:",Add(num1,num2))` and   {0} is your first argument in your case `Add(num1,num2)`.